# Is Jira 4.3.4 compatible for Jenkins 2.7 integration?

Tags: jenkins, version, jira

I am using Jira 4.3.4 version and i need to integrate it with Jenkins 2.7 version. Is it compatible? As I am working on client network I don't want to do trial and error method. Kindly advise which plugin version would be helpful

I cannot upgrade the Jira Version as it is client's purchased one. :(